# Extend user search in the users.php page to allow for searching by role and excluding specified email domains from the "users search" input box

Tags: wp-admin, users, search, user-roles, user-meta

Update: A solution for this question was provided byt @t31os_ here [Extend user search in the Wp backend area on the users.php page to allow for searching by email domain and role from the "users search" input box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/410251/extend-user-search-in-the-wp-backend-area-on-the-users-php-page-to-allow-for-sea)

The awesome code below provided by @t31os_ allows me to search for users by email domain and role and return only those users who fit the search criteria in the users.php page. I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the code so that I can search users by role and exclude all users from a certain email domain. An example would be if I searched something like "contributor notin:@gmail" I would return a list of all users who fit the role but don't have a gmail domain.

```
class wpse_410251_user_search {

private $role = false;
private $search = '';

public function __construct() { 
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );
}

public function admin_init() {
    add_action( 'pre_get_users', array( $this, 'pre_get_users' ) );
}

public function pre_get_users( $query ) {
    
    // $query is a WP_User_Query object
    
    global $pagenow;    
    
    // If not admin or the user listing
    if( !is_admin() || 'users.php' !== $pagenow )
        return;
    
    // If not a search
    if( empty( $query->get('search') ) )
        return;
    
    // Do escaping early and trim off the wildcards
    $search = trim( esc_attr( $query->get('search') ),'*' );
    
    // Check the search for appropriate search terms and set class vars, returns true/false as appropriate
    if( !$this->is_role_search( $search ) )
        return;
    
    // Update the search query var (adding back the wildcards)
    $query->set( 'search', "*{$this->search}*" );
    // Set the role query var
    $query->set( 'role', $this->role );
}
private function is_role_search( $search ) {
    
    // Split the search on space
    $search = explode( ' ', $search );
    
    // If no second search term or @ isn't the first search character
    if( !isset( $search[1] ) || '@' !== mb_substr( $search[0], 0, 1 ) )
        return false;
    
    // Bring the WP roles into scope
    global $wp_roles;
    
    // Use the $wp_roles->role_names array to iterate over and see if we get a match to an existing role
    foreach( $wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name ) {
        // Check against the lowercase slug and the display name
        if( $search[1] === $role || $search[1] === $name )
            // Store the matched role
            $this->role = $role;
    }
    // If no role set for the class, there's no match, so not a role search
    if( !$this->role )
        return false;
    
    // Store the first part of the search for updating the search query var
    $this->search = $search[0];
    
    // Else we reach here, a role has been set, return true
    return true;
}
```

}

```
$wpse_410251_user_search = new wpse_410251_user_search;
```

Comment: I posted an update to my previous answer that does this for you. ;)

Comment: Thank you @t31os_! That is awesome! I truly appreciate your help!